# What are the node providers for Genosis Network (xDai)?

Tags: brownie, gnosis-chain

Which node provider can be used to fork Genosis Network (xDai) using brownie? Alchemy, infura and moralis does not provide service. I tried getBlock but doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am a developer advocate at  [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/). Using the Chainstack platform, You can set up a Gnosis node (elastic) for free and with no rate limiting.

Here's how you can get started: [Build better with Gnosis Chain nodes](https://chainstack.com/build-better-with-gnosis-chain/)

Also, here's [Chainstack doc](https://docs.chainstack.com/operations/gnosis/tools#brownie) that shows you how to add your Gnosis node to the brownie network stack.

Hope this helps! happy BUIDLing!

Answer (score 0):

check out [www.QuickNode.com](http://www.QuickNode.com)

16 chains, 30+ networks -- including xDai / Gnosis (archive data, too!)